# SMTPConnectError when using Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using django-registration for handling of users registration. I tried to signup in order to test it, after testing it, I got this error

```
SMTPConnectError at /accounts/register/
```

Being trying to find a solution yet no success!

Full Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
111. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py" in register
187.  new_user = backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\backends\default\__init__.py" in register
79.    password, site) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in  inner
209.       return func(*args, **kwargs)  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-  packages\registration\models.py" in create_inactive_user
 85.     registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py" in send_activation_email
264.         self.user.email_user(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in email_user
 374.         send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py" in send_mail
 61.       connection=connection).send()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in send
  248.  return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in    send_messages
   85.    new_conn_created = self.open()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in open
    48.       local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())
   File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py" in __init__
    251.                 raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)

    Exception Type: SMTPConnectError at /accounts/register/
    Exception Value: (451, 'Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not  available.')
```

In Settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS=True

EMAIL_HOST='smtp.test.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER='test@test.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='f88lm'

EMAIL_PORT=587

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'test@test.com'

SERVER_EMAIL = 'test@test.com'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from my domain email hosting provider. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is an error, you have given details for an SMPT server that doesn't exist so Django can't connect to it when trying to send email. While developing, either use the [dummy email backend:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#dummy-backend)

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
```

or [run a test  email server locally.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#testing-email-sending)

Comment: But the email backend is there by default. I'm been using it before and I don't know why it's acting this way. It works fine when I input the dummy backend. I don't understand why it's acting this way. Any idea?